# About collision detection in KonvaJS

Tags: konvajs

In KonvaJS, how to detect whether a point is inside an irregular figure (e.g., pentagon) and how to detect whether a figure collides with another figure when dragging? Please write an example for reference. My central idea is (as long as it's in an irregular pattern) : collision detection and drag limits

Comment: KonvaJS does not provide collision detection of the type you seek. There are many explanations of the necessary algorithms on the web, for example at https://wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/. Please share your solution.

Comment: The reference you gave is too deep, I can't understand it, but thank you very much for your answer

Comment: You need to be prepared for some math if you are planning on doing hit testing unless your needs are very simple.  Points in rectangles and rectangle collision IS simple.  Can you simplify your requirement in some way?

Comment: Can you be clearer regarding your requirement please? For example, do you mean that the user should be able to drag shape 1 until it collides with shape2, then shape 1 cannot be dragged further? Or put another way, shape 1 may not be 'dragged over' shape 2, etc? Or is it that shape 2 must be moved when shape 1 collides with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `Konva` doesn't support collision detection.

For simple cases, you can implement your own collusions: https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Collision_Detection.html

For good collision detection support, you can use another js library. Like one of these:

- http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/
- http://brm.io/matter-js/
- http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/

So you will use "physic" library to calculate positions, collisions, etc. And you will use `Konva` for drawing.

Comment: According to your thinking, could you make a demo for me and test two triangles?