# Detect if simple svg paths overlap

Tags: javascript, math, svg, collision-detection, konvajs

I have a konvajs app that lets users draw shapes that consist of rectangles, arcs and simple polygons. I am then converting these shapes to svg. I would like to let the user drag the svg shapes around, ideally also rotate them, and detect if the svg shapes overlap each other. As far as I'm aware konva does not offer the functionality to determine such collisions. Is there a svg library suitable to this problem? If not, what would be the best approach to deal with this?[image]

Example svg paths:

```
M 632.4313725490196 330.6666666666667 L632.4313725490196 434.964705882353 L714 434.964705882353 L714 250.66666666666669 L714 250.66666666666669 Z
```

```
M 632.4313725490196 480.2980392156863 L632.4313725490196 536.156862745098 A31.372549019607845 31.372549019607845 0 0 0 663.8039215686274 567.5294117647059 L688.9019607843137 567.5294117647059 L714 542.4313725490196 L714 480.2980392156863 L632.4313725490196 480.2980392156863 Z
```

Comment: You might use some approaches explained here ["Intersection of 2 SVG Paths"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070839/intersection-of-2-svg-paths/75495494#75495494)

Comment: Some possible answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52134158/7073944